# Nodejs port error with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to push my app to heroku bu I am getting this problem where I am using the correct port number using the process.env.PORT variable but still I am getting this error message:

```
heroku[web.1]:  Starting process with command `node app.js`
app[web.1]:     info  - socket.io started
app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 49559 in development mode
heroku[web.1]:  Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 10843, should be 49559 (see environment variable PORT)
heroku[web.1]:  Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]:  Process exited
```

You can see in this error message that app is using the right port but still heroku shows the bad bind error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to load/set the port.

Comment: app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

Answer (score 8):

[Heroku will pass the port in a environment variable named `PORT`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#write_your_app), which means you can access it via `process.env`.

Simply change your code to call `listen` with the proper port

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help to me during my learning process!

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you are using flash sockets that use port 10843, and that port is not the one assigned to the app, you need to set:

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```