# Port Error on Heroku / Clojure Deployment

Tags: web-applications, deployment, clojure, heroku

This is a follow on question to my [Heroku / Clojure problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669033/beginner-qs-on-heroku-clojure-deloyment/8686421#8686421). As outlined in that thread, I was able to push my app to Heroku's master, and that deploys it.

But when I try to go to my app's URL, I get the below error. It's a bizarre port error, but I didn't think I had control over those details when deploying a Clojure app on Heroku. I think my setup's pretty straightforward. Is there anything I can do to address this error?

**Procfile**

```
    web: lein run -m http.handler
```

**http.handler**

```
    ...
    (def app      (handler/site main))
```

**Error**

```
    2011-12-31T04:10:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 41208
    2011-12-31T04:10:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL    2011-12-31T04:10:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 41208, should be 55032 (see environment variable PORT)
    2011-12-31T04:10:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2011-12-31T04:10:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-12-31T04:20:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created    2011-12-31T04:20:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting    2011-12-31T04:20:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `lein run -m http.handler`
    2011-12-31T04:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 49151    2011-12-31T04:20:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 49151, should be 39092 (see environment variable PORT)
    2011-12-31T04:20:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2011-12-31T04:20:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2011-12-31T04:20:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-12-31T04:31:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
    2011-12-31T04:31:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
    2011-12-31T04:31:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `lein run -m http.handler`
    2011-12-31T04:31:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 44321
    2011-12-31T04:31:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 44321, should be 17211 (see environment variable PORT)
    2011-12-31T04:31:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2011-12-31T04:31:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2011-12-31T04:31:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-12-31T04:44:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
    2011-12-31T04:44:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
    2011-12-31T04:45:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `lein run -m http.handler`
    2011-12-31T04:45:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 37500
    2011-12-31T04:45:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 37500, should be 14046 (see environment variable PORT)
    2011-12-31T04:45:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2011-12-31T04:45:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2011-12-31T04:45:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-12-31T04:49:22+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET bkeeping.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
    2011-12-31T04:49:31+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET bkeeping.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

There seems to be a [similar problem with Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948913/nodejs-port-error-with-heroku). But again, I don't think I have control of port assignments in a Compojure / Ring / Jetty deployment. Am I wrong? Would the behaviour change with Webnoir?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I got some really good hints, I wasn able to finally get past this. It turns out my project.clj had a defproject that included this JDPA config:

```
    :jvm-opts ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n"]
```

I should have noticed it earlier. But it just works locally, so I didn't think to question it. Hope this helps others who are having the same roadblock.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your handler binds to the correct port.

Heroku provides a port number through the environment variable `$PORT` so your code should have this somewhere after you define your `app` in your `http.handler`

```
(let [port (Integer/parseInt (System/getenv "PORT"))]
  (run-jetty app {:port port}))
```

Comment: This is definitely it, I had a similar issue which was promptly fixed by setting the port to `(System/getenv "PORT")` rather than one I had setup manually.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this. 

I modified my [Compojure http.handler](http://pastebin.com/QpSA5EXy) to pass in the PORT. But I'm still getting [the same port error](http://pastebin.com/SPegFZFq). 

I can throw up more code if need be. But my **Procfile** looks the same. And I'm pushing my custom branch to heroku with `git push heroku <my-branch>:master`.

Comment: I can't see the error with your code. Could you throw that project online, with the main handler and procfile? You can remove any other code, just leave a Hello World and I'd be happy to give it a shot.